# Is it possoble to use c# image library in monodroid?

Tags: android, image, xamarin.android

I have a c# library that uses System.Drawing.Image. As I understood monodroid doesn't support this class. How can I use my library in a monodroid project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on the contents of the drawing. If it's a regular bitmap, you can use the BitmapFactory and Bitmap classes from the Mono for Android library, which is infact the native Android stuff you'd normally use.